# Does the power port of the Raspberry Pi 3a+ have lines for transfering data?

Tags: usb, power, usb-power

Im getting a Pimoroni Power On Off Shim for my Pi 3a+ and wonder if i could use the original power micro USB-port for data stuff, like connecting a 3D printer or a webcam - since the 3a+ lacks multiple USB ports.

The Shim uses its own micro USB-Port for power supply thats why im asking.

Answer (score 4):

No.

The microUSB power connector does not have the data lines connected.  It is not a USB port.

[Pi3A+ schematics](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi3/raspberry-pi-3-a-plus-reduced-schematics.pdf)

Comment: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=228267 suggests otherwise

Comment: @Bravo That is talking about the USB port which is not the power micro USB-connector,